# Finding min distance between several points, or merging querysets with extra selects

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a bunch of objects with location attributes (PointFields). I have two special locations, and I want to know which of those locations each object is closest to and how far that is. That is, I'd like to do something like:

```
q0 = q.distance(p0).extra(select={'dist_from': p0})
q1 = q.distance(p1).extra(select={'dist_from': p1})
qq = take_obj_with_min_distance(q0, q1)
```

(The actual query will do some stuff with bboverlaps and location__distance_lt, possibly involve more than two special locations, and possibly objects with multiple location attributes. Nevertheless, I think a solution to the above will handle all that other stuff.)

Afterwards, qq should have the same elements as q, but each element has a distance attribute and a dist_from attribute, where the distance attribute is the minimum of the distance from p0 and the distance from p1, and dist_from is the point with which it achieves that minimum.

Can I do this? Is it healthy for children and other living things?

I considered merging the queries and doing this stuff with a list, but of course you can't merge queries with extra select values (such as are introduced by distance queries). Also, I'll want to filter qq some more afterwards.

Comment: Do you use a postgis database to query on?

Answer (score 0):

This page will give you the required code in a bunch of languages: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe

If you don't have too many object you might wish to do it in Python, but if you prefer querying the database it might be the best to prepare a procedure or function in SQL.